# Customizing the location of a caption on a lstlisting?

Tags: listings

I'm working on some code listings and would like to have my caption be top-left aligned with the file name (optionally) in brackets. The default settings appear to center the caption, and I can't find a way of changing the alignment.

As far as the "file name", it would be nice to enable an optional field that adds said file name in teletype font to the caption.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C, caption={Caption Here...}]
  ...
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=MyC, file="queue.c", caption={Caption...}]
  ...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `tcolorbox`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{cppStyle}{%
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    title={#2\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~(\texttt{#1})}},
    attach boxed title to top left,
    listing options={style=cppStyle}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mylisting}[main.cc]{Caption}
        #include <iostream>
        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    \end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One disadvantage however is that `autogobble` option from `lstautogobble` package does not work with `tcolorbox`. So you have to manually indent the code without any spaces/tabs before the line starts, like the following to get the desired output.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[listings,skins]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{cppStyle}{%
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    title={#2\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~(\texttt{#1})}},
    attach boxed title to top left,
    listing options={style=cppStyle}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mylisting}[main.cc]{Caption}
#include <iostream> % no indent
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
    \end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are open to use `minted` package instead of `listings`, then it works well.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[minted,skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    title={#2\ifstrempty{#1}{}{~(\texttt{#1})}},
    attach boxed title to top left,
    minted language=C++,
    minted options={autogobble},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mylisting}[main.cc]{Caption}
        #include <iostream>
        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    \end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to customize the border of a tcblisting? I don't really want a background or the ``full border''; rather, I just want top and bottom borders.

Comment: Never mind - I got it. For customizing the top and bottom borders, I used `borderline north = {1pt}{0pt}{black}, borderline south = {1pt}{0pt}{black}` and `opacityfill=0` for a transparent background.

Comment: @TheProgrammer, alternatively you can just set `leftrule=0pt` and `rightrule=0pt`.